# Android studio 3.0 error inflating info.hoang8f.widget.fbutton

Tags: maven, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading android studio form 2.3.3 to 3.0 it needs to add google maven repository and in my project an error appears in inflating info.hoang8f.widget.fbutton but before upgrading my project was working properly with FButton.
Also if I modified the build gradle to 2.3.3 the same problem still existed until I delete google maven repository form build script repositories and allprojects repositories then it works properly.

**I am wondering what cause this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

For some odd reason compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5' doesn't build. So I found this solution.

Download the library on the below link:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/hoang8f/fbutton/1.0.5/fbutton-1.0.5.aar

Step 1:

```
File >> New >> New Module >> Import JAR/AAR Package >> "Location of the downloaded library".
```

Step 2:

```
Ctr+Alt+Shift+S >> Click on the Dependencies tab >> Click the plus sign(+) >> 3 Module Dependencies >> Click Ok and Rebuild.
```

It should be fine afterwards, please let me know how it worked out for you.

Comment: ok thank you but I am wondering what cause this problem and how it is solved.I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it.

in `build.gradle (Module:app)` add this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
}
```

And add this in your root `build.gradle (project:)` at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

And in the XML configuration change `buttonColor` to `fButtonColor`.

It works for me, I hope it works with you.

library source https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button